# Is it possible to make an image end on the last grid column?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to do make a text and image overlay with a 3x3 grid, and I have it how I want it, but the image starts on the column line 2 and I want it to end on the column line 4 and have the extra space on the other side.

[Here is what I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQGPj.png)

[Here is what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q66no.png)

```
.banner-img {
    grid-column: 2 / 4;
    grid-row: 1 / 4;
}
.banner-text {
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
    grid-row: 2 / 3;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So after some research, I figured it out. All I had to do is use the `justify-self` property on the `.banner-img` and set it to `end`. For anyone needing some help on aligning grid items how you want them, [this](https://alligator.io/css/align-justify/) link is very helpful!